# Sum up appearing of each item

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, transform

I have xml file, and i want to count appearing of each item.
For example: ABC123 appear 3 times -> Qty = 3; TTTTT appear 1 time --> Qty = 1.
Please help to support to do it

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XMLFile xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BATCHID="220929-005">
  <SECTION>
    <PART SequenceNumber="2501" >
      <Materials>
        <Material>ABC123</Material>
        <Material>DEF123</Material>
      </Materials>
    </PART>
    <PART SequenceNumber="2503" >
      <Materials>
        <Material>ABC123</Material>
        <Material>DEF123</Material>
      </Materials>
    </PART>
    <PART  SequenceNumber="2502" >
      <Materials>
        <Material>TTTTT</Material>
        <Material>ABC123</Material>
      </Materials>
    </PART>
  </SECTION>
</XMLFile>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<XMLFile> 
  <BATCHID>220929-005</BATCHID>
  <DETAILS>
      <DETAIL>
        <Material>ABC123</Material>
        <Qty>3</Qty>
      </DETAIL>
      <DETAIL>
        <Material>DEF123</Material>
        <Qty>2</Qty>
    </DETAIL>
    <DETAIL>
        <Material>TTTTT</Material>
        <Qty>1</Qty>
    </DETAIL>
  </DETAILS>
</XMLFile>
```

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here.

Comment: You could also do it with xquery, if available.